# Raw PHP vs Laravel Framework : 'include' file

Tags: php, laravel

I am going through basic concepts in Laravel and I have a conceptual question.

In Raw PHP:

When I want to create an object of a class (e.g User), that is in a different directory (e.g. app\user.php) with a namespace (e.g. namespace App), I have to include that file first (using include 'app/user.php') and then add the 'use' (use App\User).

```
<?php

include 'app/user.php'; // including the file

use App\User;

$user = new User('John');
```

However, in Laravel I have seen that they don't include any file at all. They just add the 'use' keyword (use App\User.php)and then can instantiate an object of it. ($user = User::find(1)).

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
}
}
```

Can someone please explain how that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not laravel feature this is autoload_class from php.

In https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

*The `spl_autoload_register()` function registers any number of autoloaders, enabling for classes and interfaces to be automatically loaded if they are currently not defined. By registering autoloaders, PHP is given a last chance to load the class or interface before it fails with an error.*

All classes exist in composer autoload file:

```
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

Comment: Didn't know about this. Thanks for your answer